# getText() method of EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with `getText()` method. When I run this app and enter any number, also 9 it displays vcx. Is my `if` statement invalid or what?

```
public class Quadratic extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quadratic, container, false);



    // layout
    Button calc = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calcbtn); //main  button
    final EditText etfx2 = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etfx2); // x^2 etf

    final TextView tbefs = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbefs);



    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick (View v){
            String a= etfx2.getText().toString();


            if(a=="9")
            {
                tbefs.setText("asd");}
            else
            {
                tbefs.setText("vcx");
            }


        }

    });
    return rootView;
}}
```

Comment: Use `.equals()` and not `==` to compare strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: anyone knows why java developers don't deal with this string equality issue? even I saw 10+ posts about this in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a == "9" use:

```
a.equals("9")
```

And you also got something to ignore case

```
a.equalsIgnoreCase("9")
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Strings, if you write `a=="9"`, you compare the references. It means 'Is the string pointed by `a` the same string pointed by `"9"` ' i.e. are `a` and `"9"`stored in the same place in the memory.

Here you want to compare the content of your string so you have to use the `equals` method.

```
if("9".equals(a)){
    // do something
}
```